# How do I reference a div class within another div class? (inline using style tags)

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a web printing site program called pressero. 
The site in question has a section showing a kit being made up of multiple products. on each of the products displayed within the kit they all have quantities listed. My customer would like those boxes removed.

I was given a piece of inline code that does in fact do it's job (removing the qty boxes and the word quantity. The issue is that it also removes the quantity box below the individual products.

The code I was given was as follows

```
<style>
    div.pricingGridSelections{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

The issue I've found is that anything that uses the title quantity all has the same div class.

Is there any way to reference a class within a class, so I can only remove the quantity boxes from the individual products?

the individual items are in a div listed as `div.kit-class-item` well
The quantity box in the price breaks section is in a div listed as `div#pricingarea`

I tried to attach an image, but do not have enough reputation points to do so.

**One further issue is that I have no access to the actual code of the page. I'm having to inject this code into a description box for the kit item.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q11kZ.jpg

The page can be seen above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965063/target-a-css-class-inside-another-css-class

Comment: you can do this `.class1 .class2 { display: none; }`  If you want more help you should post your html code in you question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: A code snippet of you source would help. In case you can't upload an image you can always add a link to [imgur](https://imgur.com/)

Answer (score 0):

From the little code + image reference you provided all I can help you with is this:

```
#pricingarea > .kit-class-item {
  display: none;
}
```

Don't need to reference the tags(div. p, h1) in the css